# JSR 303: Is it possible to validate whole graph automatically?

Tags: java, bean-validation

Is it possible to validate whole graph automatically ? By full graph I mean the object that is being validated and all its fields that are beans too.

Or I have to traverse through them manually as shown below ?

Currently I do something like this

```
    Set<ConstraintViolation<OrderProxy>> violationsOrder = 
         validator.validate(order, Default.class, ClientGroup.class);
    Set<ConstraintViolation<OrganizationProxy>> violationsOrg =  
         validator.validate(order.getSender(), Default.class, ClientGroup.class);
    Set<ConstraintViolation<PersonProxy>> violationsPerson = 
         validator.validate(order.getSender().getPerson(), 
                               Default.class, ClientGroup.class);
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can annotate any fields that you want validated with `@Valid` and when validating your main object, it will also validate the fields.

This works for example:

```
public class Order
    @Valid
    protected Header header;
    @Valid
    protected List<Detail> details;
}
```

You would need to call

```
Set<ConstraintViolation<Order>> violationsOrder = validator.validate(order, Default.class, ClientGroup.class);
```

to get all violations (also those for the fields). You would then have to parse the causes using `getPropertyPath()` to get the exact validation source, if you need it.

```
javax.validation.Path rp = violation.getPropertyPath();
```

Comment: I don't think you should pass those classes into the validate method. Those parameters are for specifying validation groups: http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/validator/reference/en-US/html_single/#example-drive-away The validation framework should walk the object graph for any properties marked @Valid by default.